# MATLAB Runge Kutta Error using inline/subsref

Tags: matlab, runge-kutta, mathcad

Someone can help me with function A, why don't run? I can't understand the error, maybe bad write? because in B it's ok with graphic, check my method of Runge Kutta 2 Functions (f,g) and the original problem from mathcad
sorry for my bad english

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide the **actual** code, not **screenshots** of it.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case a inline function with 2 parameters (x y) is created, but all three parameters are used to call it. I recommend not to use inline and switch to function handles instead. Unused parameters are no problem here.

If you instead wish to use inline, specify the function arguments (x y t) when calling inline.